# Converting SQL to ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

I need help converting this bit of T-SQL into an ActiveRecord Query

```
select entry
from faxlog
group by entry
having count(entry) >= 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Faxlog.group(:entry).select("entry").having("count(entry) >= ?", 8)
```

Comment: To be exactly the same, you'll also need `select('entry')`.